# Storing and sending array of Integers as bytes in java

Tags: java, android, sockets

I need to send an array of bytes ( few elements have values greater than 0x7F) which I need to send to another device via socket in form of bytes. This I need to do in Java (Android application). As java has only signed byte support hence I store the values in an array of int.

Now to transmit the values over socket to the device so as it could recieve the bytes I am not able to figure out a way.

I can not cast each element in byte and construct byte array as values more than 0x7f will overflow. I can not send values like 0xff in 2 bytes as it will send two bytes with first byte having  0.

Edit:

Suppose I have 2 values 0xff and 0x02 which means 11111111 and 00000010 then how do i store it and then send in java

Edit 2: casting does not result in overflow as byte is 8 bits.

Comment: Signedness is just a representation. The socket doesn't care whether you think that `0xFF` is `-1` or `255`.

Comment: try byte[] array, it will work fine

Comment: hmm suppose i have 2 values 0xff and 0x02 which means 11111111 and 00000010 then how do i store it and then send in java

Comment: `byte[] b = new byte[] { (byte)0xFF, (byte)0x02 };` there's your bytes.

Comment: "I can not cast each element in byte and construct byte array as values more than 0x7f will overflow. ". Of course you can, and that's exactly what you need to do. There is no **overflow** involved here, all your values will fit into 8 bits.

Comment: yes , i got it.. thnks :)